# Scoping of a groovy variable inside a closure in try() to access from catch()

Tags: jenkins, groovy

how do i access the value of a variable assigned inside a closure within a try() in the catch() statement. here is what i am trying to acheive but i keep getting the initialization value that i assigned.

Note: this is for a Jenkinsfile, while uses a groovy DSL and also with some real groovy capabilities.

```
node('linux') {

        def val_log = null;

    try{

        stage('abc') {

        val_log = //some steps that generates a log that i want 

        }  

        println '$val_log'  //this works

    }

    catch(err)
        stage('mail') {
        // code to send email notification with '$val_log'  
        //--> the $val_log returns 'null' and not the 
        //value assigned in the try() part.
        }
}
```

Is there a way, to get the value for the variable inside the catch() statement.

Thank you...

Comment: This shouldn't be a scoping issue. Most likely the exception is thrown before a value gets assigned to the variable.

Comment: you are correct... that was what was happening

Comment: string interpolation requires double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try and dump the value into a file -

```
echo $BUILD_VERSION >> build_version.txt
```

and load the file value

```
def build_num = 
readFile("${env.WORKSPACE}/build_version.txt")
```

Comment: yes, this will work as the variable is not assigned with anything due to the exception thrown for the scripts failure.